# Is there some background/explanation why the Fed discontinued publishing their M3 indicator, circa 2006?

Tags: money-supply, money, federal-reserve

As Wikipedia says and as it can be easily [verified](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/28), since 2006, the Fed no longer publishes an M3 indicator (unlike the ECB which still hangs on to that notion). So is there some background or explanation to this 2006 Fed decision to abandon their M3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h6/discm3.htm:

> M3 does not appear to convey any additional information about economic activity that is not already embodied in M2 and has not played a role in the monetary policy process for many years. Consequently, the Board judged that the costs of collecting the underlying data and publishing M3 outweigh the benefits.